# Upper bound of solutions of Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $K\subset\Omega$ be a compact subset. Assume $\{f_i\}$ is a sequence of solutions of the equation $\Delta f_i=0$ on $\Omega$, with $\|f_i\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C$ for some constant number $C$ independent of $i$.

**Question**: does the inequality
$$
\|f_i\|_{L^{\infty}(K)}\leq \lambda
$$ hold for some constant number $\lambda$? (Of coursewe have that
$\|f_i\|_{L^{\infty}(K)}=\max_{K}|f_i(x)|$ due to the continuity of $f_i$)

Comment: I have specified that the $L^2$ estimate holds on the compact set $K$: if it holds on the whole $\Omega$, please feel free to correct my edit.

Comment: I just notice that your edit invalidate my proof.... (And the condition $\|f_i\|_{L^2(K)} <C$ is trivial whenever $K$ has measure zero). @DanieleTampieri

Comment: @ArcticChar, Ok, I change it. Effectively if we don't put some control on the sequence of harmonics $\{f_i\}$, easy couterexamples going at infinity in a nonintegrable way exists.

Answer (score 2):

Since $K$ is compact, there is $\delta >0$ so that for all $y\in K$, the ball $B_y(\delta)$ lies in $U$.

Let $u$ be a harmonic functions on $\Omega$. For each $x\in K$, by the mean value property for harmonic functions,

$$ u(x) = \frac{1}{|B_x(\delta)|} \int_{B_x(\delta)} u(y) dy$$

Thus by Cauchy-Schwarz,

\begin{align}
|u(x)| &\le \frac{1}{|B_x(\delta)|} \int_{B_x(\delta)} |u(y)| dy \\
&\le \frac{1}{|B_x(\delta)|}  \|u\|_{L^2(B_x(\delta))} \| 1\|_{L^2(B_x(\delta))} \\
&\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{|B_x(\delta)|}}  \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}. 
\end{align}

Thus
$$\sup |u| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega_n}\delta^{n/2}} \| u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}, $$

here $\omega_n$ is the volumn of $B_0(1)$.

Comment: Thank you. If we replace Laplace operator by another elliptic operator, can we get a same result?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the book with me, but you can try Chapter 8 of Gilbarg-Trudinger. In particular the section on Moser-iteration. @jacklion

Comment: If you elliptic operator has smooth coefficients, then you can apply $L^2$-estimates several times to get the results. @jacklion In general I guess you really need Moser iteration.

Comment: Could you tell me more about it? Does the mean value property still hold for the kernel  of  elliptic operator which has smooth coefficients?  " you can apply $L^2$-estimates several times to get the results" , Can you write it out more concretely? Thank you!

Comment: My answer uses the essential property of the Laplace operator, in particular the mean value property. Indeed the mean value property is more or less equivalent to being harmonic. I can say something but I suggest you post another question, stating clearly which elliptic operator you are working on. As I said the techniques depends on the elliptic operators given. @jacklion

Comment: Arctic Char, @jacklion, you can get the same result for the solutions of many general elliptic operators. However, I fear that for the proof [you cannot use the mean value property](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1962-0151628-9): perhaps in those cases you should use some form of [Harnack's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_inequality). (I apologize commented before seeing your latest ones).